# CakePHP redirect based on query

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to send users to certain pages based on a query string set in the url so for example: `domain.com/posts/new?back=/posts`

I take it I would set something up globally to deal with the back query string but how and where would I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to access it with `$_GET['back']` without doing anything special.

Comment: You'd want to sanitize the $_GET though. Using $this->params is cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
// Only redirect if the "back" querystring parameter was passed and is not empty.
if ( ! empty($this->params['url']['back']) )
  $this->redirect($this->params['url']['back']);
```

Source: http://book.cakephp.org/view/963/The-Parameters-Attribute-params

Comment: How would I apply something like this globally though so if any url had this extra query string attached then it would work? Thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. Do your want any request with ?back= to automatically forward the user? Or do you want the user to be forward once a form is submitted? To apply this globally so that any URL with ?back= forwards the user right away, use the beforeFilter function of the app controller.

Comment: In your app_model, if you want to redirect after a new record is created or updated, add an afterSave() method with the code above and it will be called on each save for any model.

Comment: @William - This would work assuming that ?back=... is in the form's action `<form action="http://example.org/controller/action?back=...>` otherwise that won't work. @Cameron's question is somewhat vague as it's not clear when the query string parameter is being passed. With that said, redirecting from a model is a bad idea. It would make more sense to put this in the controller directly after the save or saveAll call.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I had a brain-lapse. He could potentially put it in the app_controller beforeFilter() to check for the back param and then redirect accordingly.